# gridview.count doesn't scroll flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gridview, overflow

In my app i put gridview.count in column widget but gridview.count doesn't scroll and give overflow in bottom so please give some suggestion

Here is my code

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image.asset(
      "images/background.png",
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,bottom: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Spacer(flex: 2),
                      Text(
                        'Interests',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Expanded(
                        child:SvgPicture.asset(
                          "images/vector.svg",
                          height: 30.0,
                          width: 30.0,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 90,left: 10,right: 10),
                child: GridView.count(
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                     crossAxisCount: 3,
                     crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                     mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                       return Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                         child: Container(
                           child: SvgPicture.asset(
                             "images/register_top_logo_new.svg",
                           ),
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                           height: 135.0,
                           width: 135.0,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             border: Border.all(
                               width: 1.0,
                               color: Color(0xFFF9AD16),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
                       );
                     },
                     ),
                   ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
       ),
     ),
    ],
   );
 }
```

here is log i get when I run the app

```
I/flutter (16748): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (16748):   Column
I/flutter (16748):   file:///C:/Users/mayur/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter/webinar-mobile/lib/activities/interests_activity.dart:30:22
I/flutter (16748): 
I/flutter (16748): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter (16748): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter (16748): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter (16748): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter (16748): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter (16748): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter (16748): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter (16748): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter (16748): like a ListView.
I/flutter (16748): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#42dda relayoutBoundary=up5 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter (16748):   needs compositing
I/flutter (16748):   creator: Column ← Center ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
I/flutter (16748):     CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter (16748):     _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#417d7 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ←
I/flutter (16748):     PhysicalModel ← ⋯
I/flutter (16748):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter (16748):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=640.0)
I/flutter (16748):   size: Size(360.0, 640.0)
I/flutter (16748):   direction: vertical
I/flutter (16748):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter (16748):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter (16748):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter (16748):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter (16748): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter (16748): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (16748): unhandled element metadata; Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#bcd18(), name: "images/register_top_logo_new.svg", colorFilter: null)
```

[image: this i got when I run this app overflow in bottom and doesn't scroll]

So here gridview.count doesn't scroll,i tried to use gridview.builder but it give same error so tell me where I made mistake in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap your grid view with Expanded widget like this

```
Expanded(
   child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 90,left: 10,right: 10),
                child: GridView.count(
                     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                     crossAxisCount: 3,
                     crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                     mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                       return Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                         child: Container(
                           child: SvgPicture.asset(
                             "images/register_top_logo_new.svg",
                           ),
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                           height: 135.0,
                           width: 135.0,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             border: Border.all(
                               width: 1.0,
                               color: Color(0xFFF9AD16),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
                       );
                     },
                     ),
                   ),
              ),
)
```

Comment: can you explain why we wrap that in expanded

Comment: When the parent height or width is not define or unbounded and if its's child height/width is bigger than the height/width of the screen then flutter throw overflowed pixel exception. So in this case we need to wrap that child with Expanded or Flexible. These widget take expanded area for the child. Please go through https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SingleChildScrollView` above `Column` which will scroll the inner GridView also add

physics: `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, inside

```
GridView.count(
//.... existing code
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

)

This happens because Column and Gridview both taking full height on the screen, so here one should stop scrolling. so with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`, we are telling GridView not to scroll so that parent widget can be scroll.

**Code:**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListView Sample"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "images/background.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
            body: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Spacer(flex: 2),
                            Text(
                              'Interests',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                height: 30.0,
                                width: 30.0,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10, bottom: 90, left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: GridView.count(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        children: List.generate(
                          20,
                          (index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                height: 135.0,
                                width: 135.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    width: 1.0,
                                    color: Color(0xFFF9AD16),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Note: I have replaced image assets with the `container` as I don't have an image

**Output:**

[image]